# Integral literal division assigned to float - why is the result wrong?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    float a=5/9;
    cout << a;
}
```

This code prints 0 and not 0.555 - what is the problem? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
5/9
```

is a division of two integers and its result is `0`. If you want the operation done in `float`s then at least one operand has to be a `float`:

```
5/9.f
```